# Append value to args in rust macro

Tags: rust, macros

How can I prepend or append a value to a rust macro variadic argument. For example, if the macro is defined like `assert_eq` (being the following the relevant part)

```
($left:expr, $right:expr, $($arg:tt)+)
```

How do I add elements to `arg`?

Comment: What do you mean by append values to `arg`? Do you mean that you want to recursively call the macro with `arg` matching `$($arg)+` + something else?

Comment: Could you add an example of using the macro, along with what the expected output would be

Comment: @EvilTak Indeed I have a macro `mymacro!(x, y, "msg {} here {}", " some text" )` which in turn should call `assert_eq!(a, b, "msg {} here {}", " some text", "a specific text goes here")` (`a` and `b` dependes on `x` and `y` but do not pay attention to that part)

Comment: Does this work for you? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4731b149ee9c3a98f92bce6afa92d1eb What have you tried?

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks! Thatt was surprisingly easy.